# Counter counting up/down depending on which side you push

Tags: jquery

I have these product counters where originally I had it so when you click the element with .btn class the counter would go up, however their would be no way to make it come back down if needed. I want it so that if they click the element with .add-one class the counter will go up one. and the other way around for if they click .remove-one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;

  $(".btn").each(function() {

    $(this).click(function() {
      // var thisProductPrice = parseFloat($(this).find($('.product-price-original')).text()),
      //  count = parseInt($(this).find('.product-counter').text()) + 1,
      //  newPrice = (thisProductPrice * count).toFixed(2);

      $(".add-one").click(function() {
        var thisProductPrice = parseFloat($(this).find($('.product-price-original')).text()),
          count = parseInt($(this).find('.product-counter').text()) + 1,
          newPrice = (thisProductPrice * count).toFixed(2);

        $(this).siblings($('.product-counter')).text(count),
          $(this).siblings($('.product-price')).text(newPrice)
      });
      $(".remove-one").click(function() {
        var thisProductPrice = parseFloat($(this).find($('.product-price-original')).text()),
          count = parseInt($(this).find('.product-counter').text()) - 1,
          newPrice = (thisProductPrice * count).toFixed(2);

        $(this).siblings($('.product-counter')).text(count),
          $(this).siblings($('.product-price')).text(newPrice)
      });
      $(this).addClass("locked");
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="remove-one">-</div>
    <span class="product-btn size">S: $</span>
    <div class="product-price">9.95</div>
    <span class="counter">(<div class="product-counter">0</div>)</span>
    <div class="product-price-original">9.95</div>
    <div class="add-one">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="remove-one">-</div>
    <span class="product-btn size">M: $</span>
    <div class="product-price">11.95</div>
    <span class="counter">(<div class="product-counter">0</div>)</span>
    <div class="product-price-original">11.95</div>
    <div class="add-one">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="remove-one">-</div>
    <span class="product-btn size">L: $</span>
    <div class="product-price">14.95</div>
    <span class="counter">(<div class="product-counter">0</div>)</span>
    <div class="product-price-original">14.95</div>
    <div class="add-one">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant CSS to the snippet I made for you

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to stackoverflow so i'm nt sure how to add the css to the snippit, i have added the css. I am using sass though, i hope that's not an issue?

Comment: 1. "edit this snippet" and 2. yes it is a problem. - it does not work with sass 3. You are using `find`wrong. Your `var thisProductPrice = parseFloat($(this).find($('.product-price-original')).text()),` should likely be 
        `var thisProductPrice = parseFloat($(this).parent().find($('.product-price-original')).text()),`

Comment: Please add RELEVANT CSS - your sass has nothing to do with the HTML you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.add-one` and `.remove-one` elements doesn't have child element so `.find()` will not work.

You should traverse upto parent `.btn` element using `.closest()`/`.parent()` then use `.find()` to target the desired element.

```
var btn = $(this).closest('.btn'); //Target parent
var thisProductPrice = parseFloat(btn.find('.product-price-original').text()), //target desired element
```

You should attach event handler with button's directly no need of `.each()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;

  $(".add-one").click(function() {
    var btn = $(this).closest('.btn');
    var thisProductPrice = parseFloat(btn.find('.product-price-original').text()),
      count = parseInt(btn.find('.product-counter').text()) + 1,
      newPrice = (thisProductPrice * count).toFixed(2);

    btn.find('.product-counter').text(count);
    btn.find('.product-price').text(newPrice);
  });

  $(".remove-one").click(function() {
    var btn = $(this).closest('.btn');
    var thisProductPrice = parseFloat(btn.find('.product-price-original').text()),
      count = parseInt(btn.find('.product-counter').text()) - 1,
      newPrice = (thisProductPrice * count).toFixed(2);

    btn.find('.product-counter').text(count);
    btn.find('.product-price').text(newPrice);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="remove-one">-</div>
    <span class="product-btn size">S: $</span>
    <div class="product-price">9.95</div>
    <span class="counter">(<div class="product-counter">0</div>)</span>
    <div class="product-price-original">9.95</div>
    <div class="add-one">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="remove-one">-</div>
    <span class="product-btn size">M: $</span>
    <div class="product-price">11.95</div>
    <span class="counter">(<div class="product-counter">0</div>)</span>
    <div class="product-price-original">11.95</div>
    <div class="add-one">+</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="remove-one">-</div>
    <span class="product-btn size">L: $</span>
    <div class="product-price">14.95</div>
    <span class="counter">(<div class="product-counter">0</div>)</span>
    <div class="product-price-original">14.95</div>
    <div class="add-one">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have voted to close - it is very localised and just needed a parent/closest to work

Comment: This has been answered, i will close it now, thank you to all!